# Unity 3D VR: How to use GVR SDK in Window Platform

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr-sdk

I use Window Platform for my Unity VR project. When I try to implement Google VR SDK, In the Unity Editor, GVR works fine. However, When I build exe file,

[image: GVR Unity Editor]

Image looks like this.[image]

Is there anyway to use GVR in Window Platform?? thank you.

Comment: I guess you are using unity version less than 5.6 (as >5.6 versions have GVR integrated and you don't have access to it on windows platform, also it does not split the screen in editor). I also assume you are using GVR sdk version less than 1.6 (as >1.6 needs Unity >5.6). So in this situation 1 thing I'd try is to set Distortion Correction of the GVRViewer to Unity (non-native, don't remember the exact name) and build again. However GVR was never intended to run on Windows platform so I wouldn't have my hopes high.

Comment: Doesn't it say specifically that GVR won't work on Windows platform? There should be a warning saying the platform is not supported every time you run in editor.